# Strange behaviour of \dotsc with unicode latin modern font

Tags: unicode

The spacing with `\dotsc` is a little "strange"
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket},math-style=french]{unicode-math}
%\usepackage[StylisticSet=4]{fourier-otf}
\usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}

\begin{document}    
    $E=\{a_1,\dotsc,a_n\}$ et $a_1$, $\dotsc$, $a_n$
\end{document}
```

And here is what I get:
[image]

As you can see, the spacing with the dots is not the same within the set E and outside the set. When I used PdfLaTeX, the spacing was the same. It seems to come from the latin modern font because if I uncomment the line I commented, I get with the Erewhon font:
[image]
The dots are nicer (but it's a question of taste) and the spacing is the same. In fact, when I zoom in, the spacing seems to be different too. I tried with dots and ldots but the spacings are also different.
Am I doing anything wrong?

When I think that a colleague had told me it was very simple moving from pdflatex to lualatex, I disagree. The `varnothing` symbol had changed, the `\setminus` symbol was invisible, ...

Comment: It's not the same in either case. Inside the set you get a thin space, outside you get a normal interword space.

Comment: note your last comment that is switching math layout to unicode math which is making essentially everything different but it's not actually required to do that to switch to lualatex

Comment: Thank you @egreg I understand better, now

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle I should have been more specific in my post. I use Unicode because of the option French math style

Answer (score 1):

The ellipsis (three dots) in math mode were originally implemented by Knuth in `\ldots` plain TeX macro. Three dots are inserted, each of them as punctuation mark, i.e. there is `\tinmuskip` between three dots. The explicit `\thinmuskip` is added after the last dot because the dots are declared as `\mathinner` in the `\ldots` macro. The sequence `$,\ldots,$` yields to comma tm dot tm dot tm dot tm comma (the tm means `\thinmuskip` here). So, all spaces are equal.

The Unicode math brings news: there is a special character … (unicodeellipsis, U+2026) in the font. The font designer typically doesn't insert the same space between these dots like `\thinmuskip` -- it is impossible because `\thinmuskip` is stretchable space. The spaces between dots in font in unicodeellipsis character is typically smaller than the `\thinmuskip` value. You have `\thinmuskip` before and after … but not inside the … character.

You can declare  `\mathchardef\ldotp="602E` (dot as a punctuation character) and keep the `\ldots` macro from plain TeX: `\def\ldots{\mathinner{\ldotp\ldotp\ldotp}}` after Unicode math is loaded. Then you have equal spaces like Knuth defined in plain TeX.

Note, that OpTeX keeps the `\ldots` macro like in plain TeX and a user can use it or the `\unicodeellipsis`, which uses the single character … from the font.

Answer (score 0):

In the set notation you get a thin space; in the second case you get a normal interword space: they're usually different. And they differ also in your example where you claim they're the same.

Let's make a comparison:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket},math-style=french]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[StylisticSet=4]{fourier-otf}
\usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}

\begin{document}    
    $E=\{a_1,\dotsc,a_n\}$ et $a_1$, $\dotsc$, $a_n$

\showoutput

\end{document}
```

The relevant parts in the log file are

```
....\TU/Erewhon-Math.otf(1)/m/n/10 ,
....\glue(\thinmuskip) 1.111
....\TU/Erewhon-Math.otf(1)/m/n/10 …
```

for the first space before the dots and

```
....\TU/erewhon(0)/m/n/10 ,
....\glue(\spaceskip) 2.11 plus 1.05605 minus 0.70262
....\mathon
....\TU/Erewhon-Math.otf(1)/m/n/10 …
```

for the second space before the dots.

The effect is more evident with Latin Modern (commenting out `fourier.otf`), because the `\spaceskip` turns out to be

```
....\TU/lmr/m/n/10 ,
....\glue(\spaceskip) 3.33 plus 1.66666 minus 1.10889
....\mathon
....\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 …
```

so 1.22pt wider.

Second experiment, with `pdflatex` and Erewhon

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}

\usepackage{erewhon}
\usepackage[utopia]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}    
    $E=\{a_1,\dotsc,a_n\}$ et $a_1$, $\dotsc$, $a_n$

\showoutput

\end{document}
```

The relevant parts are

```
....\glue(\thinmuskip) 1.66663
....\hbox(1.20999+0.025)x10.80322
.....\OML/zutmi/m/it/10 :
.....\glue(\thinmuskip) 1.66663
.....\OML/zutmi/m/it/10 :
.....\glue(\thinmuskip) 1.66663
.....\OML/zutmi/m/it/10 :
....\glue(\thinmuskip) 1.66663
```

for the space before the first dots and

```
....\T1/erewhon-TLF/m/n/10 ,
....\glue 2.10999 plus 1.05605 minus 0.70226
....\mathon
....\hbox(1.20999+0.025)x10.80322
.....\OML/zutmi/m/it/10 :
.....\glue(\thinmuskip) 1.66663
.....\OML/zutmi/m/it/10 :
.....\glue(\thinmuskip) 1.66663
.....\OML/zutmi/m/it/10 :
```

in the second case. Again, the spaces are not the same.

Comment: Thank you @egreg for this very complete answer. I have so much to learn about LaTeX